# Raise event after Workbook deactivate finishes

Tags: c#, excel, interop, openxml, excel-interop

I am trying to trigger and event after the `WokbookDeactivate` event is finished because I need to write some metadata into the file and it can be done only when the Excel file is completely closed.

While using `WokbookDeactivate` the workbook still appears as active and if I try to run the code that access the excel file it raises an exception "is being used by another process..."

**ThisAddin_Startup**

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.WorkbookOpen += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(Application_WorkbookOpen);
    this.Application.WorkbookDeactivate += Application_WorkbookDeactivate;
}
```

**EventHandler**

```
void Application_WorkbookDeactivate(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
    Excel.Application excelApp = this.Application;
    string filePath = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.FullName;
    string userName = GeneralFunctions.getUser();

    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath) && Metadata.ContainsKey(filePath) && Metadata[filePath])
        {
            Metadata.Remove(filePath);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

After Deactivate I need to run another event that check if the key of the excel file was removed from the Metadata. That means I can edit the document using the OpenXML function...

I tried to attach two events to the Deactivate, but the excel workbook is still open when the first one finishes.

Any idea?

***Another approach:***
I created a Timer property `System.Timers.Timer _tm;` and call a method to initialize it.

```
void Application_WorkbookDeactivate(Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
    Excel.Application excelApp = this.Application;
    string filePath = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.FullName;

    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath) && Metadata.ContainsKey(filePath) && Metadata[filePath] && Wb.FullName.Equals(filePath))
        {
            StartWrite(filePath);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

private void StartWrite(string filePath)
{
    _tm = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
    _tm.Elapsed += (sender, args) => _tm_Elapsed(sender, filePath);
    _tm.Enabled = true;
}

void _tm_Elapsed(object sender, string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        ((System.Timers.Timer)sender).Enabled = false;
        string userName = GeneralFunctions.getUser();
        if (this.Application != null && Metadata[filePath])
        {
            // Do stuff with the file
            _tm.Stop();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably your application is still holding references to COM objects. Have you tried calling `excelApp.Quit`? Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.quit.aspx).

Comment: If that doesn't resolve you could additionally try this:
`Marshal.ReleaseComObject (excelApp);`
`excelApp = null;`